# Where can I find Refrence manuals for SQL and PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, manual

Are there any Manuals available,which cater to the needs of SQL and PLSQL developers in the industry. I tried to search,but  I found nothing like that of of equal to  PHP's manual quality in .chm Format.

So, can anyone give me or share their useful material direct links to PLSQL and SQL manuals in .chm format, for Quick development and learning along the way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is there a reason that you are restricting yourself to just CHM manuals?  Oracle provides rather copious documentation in HTML and PDF format.  For example

- The [SQL Language Reference](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/to_toc?pathname=server.112/e17118/toc.htm)
- The [SQL Language Quick Reference](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/to_toc?pathname=server.112/e17119/toc.htm)
- The [PL/SQL Language Reference](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/to_toc?pathname=appdev.112/e17126/toc.htm)
- The [PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/to_toc?pathname=appdev.112/e16760/toc.htm)

along with dozens and dozens of other manuals that deal with more specialized bits of functionality.

All the Oracle database documentation is online at http://tahiti.oracle.com.  You can download PDF or HTML versions of the manuals for whatever version(s) of Oracle you happen to be working with there.

Comment: I personally like .chm format, as it allows quick search of any function or construct in the language.

Comment: Actually ,I need some offline Reference Manual download for both the mentioned languages.

Comment: @Demla - I added the link to the Oracle documentation site if you want to download these or other manuals.

Comment: @carpenteri - I am wondering why it's been downvoted twice as well.  I'd be happy to improve it if I can.

Comment: They are also available in MOBI format for your Kindle or whatever. Calibre does a good job of converting ebook formats but only allows a conversion FROM chm not TO.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of learning SQL from a beginners standpoint I cannot recommend "Learning SQL" by O'Reilly enough.

[http://www.amazon.com/Learning-SQL-Alan-Beaulieu/dp/0596520832](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596520832)

Another great learning tool / reference is W3 School's SQL tutorials found here:

http://w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

And for PLSQL look no further then "Oracle PL/SQL Programming".

[http://www.amazon.com/Oracle-PL-SQL-Programming-Versions/dp/0596514468/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1312568800&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596514468)

Comment: btw if you want them I have a few LEGAL chms if ya want them pm me.

Comment: my ID: demlaip@gmail.com, btw what is pm in ur words. And thanks sir.

Comment: "pm" means private message Ill send you an email now.